# White gap on the right of the screen, using BS 3.3.7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this project assigned from school where I need to create a webpage using Bootstrap and it states that we can't have any gaps, or horizontal scroll bars, otherwise - fail.

Everything is fine on desktop browser when I resize the window, but when I open my page on a smartphone, I'm getting white gap on the right side. But when I rotate my phone and view my page in landscape mode, the gap isn't there and everything seems fine. I've been looking for hours now how to fix this and so far have found something about .container-fluid, margins, paddings and some other things (tried using them on my page file, but not working, probably because I don't know how or what to change). This is my first time creating a page, let alone a bootstrap one so I'm very new to this.

Here is the page on desktop, resized with no gap - [image]

Here it is on my smartphone in portrait mode - http://pho.to/Acq4o (2nd image) As you can see, it's pretty annoying. Also what I've noticed is that my navigation bar doesn't have a gap after it, the gap appears only below navbar, strange. You can also see landscape mode in the same link (1st image) and it's perfectly fine.

I really appreciate everyone trying to help, thank you in advance!

Edit: `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">`
`

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">

      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button>

    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Auto Pasaule</a>

  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

  <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Twitter</a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li><a href="#galerija">Galerija</a>

      <li><a href="#kontakti">Kontakti</a>

      <li><a href="#anketa">Anketa</a>

      <li><a href="#cv">CV</a>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

`

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help when you don't show us any code?

Comment: Where is the page content code? I only see navbars. Please don't post pics hosted on external link bait

Comment: I finally figured out why I was having the gap. It was because of google maps script I added in "Contact" section. It was stretching my page hence the white gap. I removed it and now there isn't a gap anymore when viewing from smartphone. Although I don't know why it didn't before, since i could view it fine from desktop when resizing chrome. Anyway, I resolved it.
@ZimSystem Sorry, I will remove those links. Didn't mean to brake rules.